# How to run systemd on ubuntu 14.10 utopic in a docker container?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, systemd

Installed systemd on the host with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemd-sysv
copied new /etc/default/grub file with: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet init=/lib/systemd/systemd"
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Works fine.

And then trying to install systemd in the docker container with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemd-sysv
(no grub detected so skipping grub part)
exit (exiting docker container)
docker restart container_name (reboot docker container)
docker exec -it container_name bash (login to docker container)
```

When I try to run `systemd` in a docker container it gives me the following error:

```
Trying to run as user instance, but the system has not been booted with systemd.
```

How can I run systemd in a ubuntu utopic docker container? 
Is grub necessary to make systemd run in a docker container? 
Basically, how do I make this work?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/420917/75668

Comment: I know but there is no grub present in the docker container, so I can't completely finish it. Is grub necessary in a container?

Comment: You missed the point: **The host must be booted with systemd.**

Comment: Well, it is, which I also mentioned in my question.

Comment: No, it isn't, which is why you got the error message.

Comment: Apologies, I did install systemd succesfully on the host, but my question wasn't clear enough so I've updated it. Reflects the actual situation now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21283/discussion-between-hyperfocus-and-michael-hampton).